# How to delete and create a new firefox profile from tty1?

Tags: firefox

How to delete and create a new firefox profile from TTY1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**WARNING**: This will delete everything in the Firefox config - there is no undo.

With that out of the way, to do that, you can run the following in the terminal.

```
rm -rf ~/.mozilla
rm -rf ~/.cache/mozilla
```

This will delete local settings and cache, including the extensions.

**EDIT:** Thanks to one of the comments, there is a way to backup the firefox config. To do that, follow the line below instead.

`cd ~/.mozilla && mkdir backup && cp -r ./extensions ./backup && cp -r ./firefox* ./backup && rm -rf ./firefox* ./extensions`

Comment: It works fine..

Comment: To have some "undo" it's possible to just rename the directory to some other, so it can be undone later, if it's needed.

Comment: @LGB - Correct.

Comment: When using `rm` with the `r` flag, especially when also using the `f` flag, and especially when providing advice that might be followed by novice users, I recommend avoiding commands that will wipe out the whole home directory if an accidental space is added. In this situation, you can just delete the `.mozilla` folder along with its contents, by running `rm -r .mozilla`.

Answer (score 8):

To **delete** all Firefox settings type:

```
mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla.backup
```

in a terminal. On next startup Firefox will create a new `~/.mozilla` directory for a new session with default settings.

To **restore** your settings type:

```
mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla.newbackup
mv ~/.mozilla.backup ~/.mozilla
```

This way you can create a variety of settings to restore when needed.

Comment: This seems to be good idea..+1 here