# Firefox ignoring it's own preference/settings in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I checked out this following link: [Firefox ignoring it's own preference/settings in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279727/firefox-ignoring-its-own-preference-settings-in-12-10) but it wasn't resolved.

My specific situation is that I installed Ubuntu 16.04 onto an SSD and then synchronized Firefox.  I keep getting warnings about closing all tabs.  In the past, with 14.04, it worked correctly.

I am thinking I had to manually change a setting somewhere in a configuration file, maybe, but my searches are drawing a blank.

---

### Unresolved

I tried the solutions below, I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 on top of what I had, and I tried upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.

I finally did a clean install of 16.04 on a new HDD so I no longer have the problem.

Comment: Maybe you ran Firefox as root at some point (some kittens died when you did that!) and now you do not have write permissions on some of its config files any more. Try if running the command `sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.mozilla/firefox` solves your problem. It should save your settings from now on if that was the issue. Please report back whether it worked and I will convert this comment into an answer.

Comment: Check your profile folder (which you can find in `about:preferences`) and see if there's a "user.js" file. If that file exists, maybe it's the cause of the problem. You should move it to the trash, restart Firefox, and see what happens.

Comment: @ByteCommander - I ran the command but to no avail.  I did get a strange thing, though.  The first time I ran Firefox after doing that, I got a check-box with an option not to ask to verify closing multiple tabs.  I checked it and the next time I loaded FF, I got the dialog box without the check box.

Comment: Strange. No idea then.

Comment: @TSJNachos117 I went to   about:preferences and found what I usually see in Edit:preferences.  I  didn't see the file, and even went to the .mozilla folder and searched it and all subsfolders for the 'user.js' file and didn't see one.  I did find signedInUser.json, but I don't know if it's the same.

Comment: I renamed signedInUser.json to xxx.signedInUser.json and all that happened was that I had to sign in to sync.  Still no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is still unresolved, but has become an issue for Firefox rather than Ubuntu.  The issue has spread to Firefox on all my computers whether Linux or Windows.