# How can I get Firefox to stop crashing on startup?

Tags: firefox, crash, reboot, ubuntu-mate

I forgot to close Firefox before rebooting my system, and now Firefox gives me this dialog whenever I try to open it:

> We're sorry
>
> Firefox had a problem and crashed

I'm running Ubuntu MATE off a 64 GB microSD card in a Raspberry Pi 3B with 1 GB RAM, 1.2 GHz quad-core processor, and an integrated WiFi chip. The OS and all packages are up-to-date. I've tried running it from the command line as a normal user, with sudo, and as root. I ran `apt-get install firefox --reinstall`, and that had no effect. I've also tried both answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32527/how-to-delete-and-create-a-new-firefox-profile-from-tty1) How can I fix this?

Comment: How  much RAM do you have? Did you tried `firefox --safe-mode`?

Comment: @N0rbert 1 GB, it's a Pi 3B

Comment: @dsstorefile From what I can tell, that should be in the /,mozilla/ folder, which isn't there. Running `ls ~/home/zenon/.mozilla/` returns an error that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: How about `ls ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox`?

Comment: Thank you! I thought `~` just meant the filesystem. `/.cache/` shows a `hzad34mx.default` and `/.mozilla/firefox` shows things including `profiles.ini`

Comment: I'm still having the problem. I tried some more things which I linked to in the question. Any ideas?

Comment: @N0rbert - Just now saw your edit with `firefox --safe-mode`. Ran that, same result.

Comment: Have you tried `rm -rf ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla/firefox`? Does `firefox --safe-mode` help?

Answer (score -1):

If it's `/dev/shm` permission error, then just do `sudo chmod a+x /dev/shm/`

***Note***: `/dev/shm` is a shared memory device, which the firefox uses.